# How would you have a progress bar/spinner going for the duration of another function? (KSH)

Tags: function, spinner, wait, ksh, progress

Suppose I have a working spinner printout function we'll call `spinfunction` and then a function that processes a bunch of things called `myfunction`

Using Bash or KSH, how would I get this spinner running at the bottom of my shell for the duration of `myfunction`?

Comment: *at the bottom of my shell* -- I guess you mean "at the bottom of the screen"?

Answer (score 3):

since you can't background functions as far as I know, you'll either have to do the spinner from the work function or run the spinner in a sub shell and have some way to kill it.

I'd tell my team members not to put progress indicators on their shell functions - it muddies the output with lots of carriage return and spinner text, but with much less value than logging.  It also tends to break reasonable expectations for shell programs - that when executing they have access to standard out and error.  There's a reason spinners aren't a standard part of inbox command line output!  Just my 2¢

Answer (score 0):

I once created a function with a case statement around a global variable `$__spin`, something like:

```
spinfunction() {
  case $__spin in
  (1) printf "\r|";  __spin=2;;
  (2) printf "\r/";  __spin=3;;
  (3) printf "\r-";  __spin=4;;
  (*) printf "\r\\"; __spin=1;;
  esac
}
```

This will always print the next character in the sequence at the start
of the current line.  If you want it in a fixed position while other
output is being processed, you need to fiddle with `tput` and a lot of
hassle.

---

For testing, append the following and name the script `spinner.sh`

```
(
module=spinner
name=${0##*/}
case ${name%.sh} in
($module) 
  while sleep 0.2; do
    spinfunction
  done
;;
esac
)
```

Run it with `ksh spinner.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do not want to change `myfunction` and you know it writes to a logfile,
you can let your spinfunction make an action every time something is written to the logfile.
Or you can call `ps` in a loop (with a sleep) until `myfunction` is finished.